# arranging a set of names such that two names are printed as one solution

Tags: python

How can arrange a set of names so that each solution has two names.for example
["bob", "sally", "jane"]

the outcome should be like;
bob & sally,
sally & jane etc, using python

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework? Look up "permutation".

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> li = ["bob", "sally", "jane"]
>>> for i in itertools.combinations(li, 2):
    print i
```

And you get:

```
('bob', 'sally')
('bob', 'jane')
('sally', 'jane')
```

Check out the docs for [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), especially on [combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). There are good code examples there showing how it really works.

Comment: Beat me to it, +1. OPs question _could_ also ask for the `pairwise` recipe in the docs of itertools, though I doubt that's what he meant.

Comment: Good point, @lazyr. I think you can make it an answer so the OP can pick and choose.

Comment: Nah, it's rather far-fetched, and reading my comment, he knows.