# Print two random, different names from a set of names

Tags: python, random

```
import random  
mylist = ['anthony', 'kris', 'james', 'vinny', 'joe']  
randomList1 = random.randrange(0,len(mylist))  
randomList2 = random.randrange(0,len(mylist))  
name2 = mylist[randomList1]  
name3 = mylist[randomList2]  
print 'The group will consist of', name2, 'and', name3,'. '
```

Is the code in question, this isn't for me but the person doing it is trying to print two random names from mylist, but of course with the current code it occasionally will print two of the same

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106828/arranging-a-set-of-names-such-that-two-names-are-printed-as-one-solution) may be of some use for answering, but I've tried a few things to help him but I'm no python expert and I can't think straight at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> import random  
>>> mylist = ['anthony', 'kris', 'james', 'vinny', 'joe']
>>> random.sample(mylist, 2)
['james', 'vinny']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> mylist = ['anthony', 'kris', 'james', 'vinny', 'joe']
>>> sample(mylist,2)
['kris', 'vinny']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.sample` setting `k = 2`

```
random.sample(population, k)
```

Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence.

Answer (score 0):

After picking the first name, remove it from the list and pick a random name from that new list.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no `random.sample`, I would suggest

```
import random  
mylist = ['anthony', 'kris', 'james', 'vinny', 'joe']  
randomList1 = random.randrange(0, len(mylist))  
randomList2 = random.randrange(0, len(mylist) - 1)
if randomList2 == randomList1:
    randomList2 = len(mylist) - 1
name2 = mylist[randomList1]  
name3 = mylist[randomList2]  
print 'The group will consist of', name2, 'and', name3,'. '
```

i. e., take one less, and if it happens to be the same as the first one, take the last one instead.